# select columns from multiple tables using nested query in sqlite3

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have 3 tables - `lists`, `items`, `list_items` in my SQLite3 database. The table `list_items` is a many-to-many table comprising of following columns - `list_id`, `item_id`, `quantity` - where `list_id` is from `lists` table, `item_id` is from `items` table and `quantity` is a new field. In my application, I would like to display item names and their corresponding quantities for a given list. I am able to fetch all the items in a given list using this SQL query:

```
select item_name from items where item_id in (select item_id from list_items where list_id=1)
```

But I am not aware of how to fetch the column quantity from list_items along with the names in the above query. Can someone please help me fixing this query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below - using join

```
select item_name,quantity
from items i inner join list_items li on i.item_id =li.item_id 
where list_id=1
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not do the `JOIN` ?

```
select i.item_name, li.quantity   
from items i inner join
     list_items li
     on li.item_id = i.item_id
where li.list_id = 1;
```